# how to resolve feature column deprecated warning in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

my tensorflow version is 2.4.1, when I want to transfer my data into feature column and create the estimator, the terminal said that my feature column API is deprecated. I feel really confused. Can anyone help me? THX!

This is my code:

```
csv_file = 'train.csv'
csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory = False)
csv_df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data) 

CONTI_FEATURES = ['Age', 'Smoking']
CATE_FEATURES = ['Gender', 'ICD9Code']

def print_transformation(feature, continuous, size):
   
    feature_names = [feature]

    d = dict(zip(feature_names, [csv_data[feature]]))

    if continuous == True:
        c = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature)
        feature_columns = [c]
    else:
        c = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(feature, hash_bucket_size=size)
        c_indicator = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(c)
        feature_columns = [c_indicator]

## Use input_layer to print the value
    input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(
        features=d,
        feature_columns=feature_columns
        )
    
    return input_layer

Age_feature = print_transformation(feature = "Age", continuous = True, size = 2)
Smoking_feature = print_transformation(feature = "Smoking", continuous = True, size = 2)
Gender_feature = print_transformation(feature = "Gender", continuous = False, size = 2)
Diagnosis_feature = print_transformation(feature = "ICD9Code", continuous = False, size = 1000)

continuous_features = [Age_feature, Smoking_feature]
categorical_features = [Gender_feature, Diagnosis_feature]

model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
  n_classes = 2,
  model_dir = "ongoing/train",
  feature_columns = categorical_features + continuous_features
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deprecation Warning messages are needed to inform developers who want to use an actual version of TensorFlow what is going to happen in the future, and give them time to adapt.

Nothing to worry about Deprecation warnings, it will not hamper your code performance.
You can turn off the warnings by using following either one of the code snippet

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Alternate option is to use below code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: @RA.IBOY, Thank you for acknowledging. Can you upvote and accept the answer.